# How to get AnchorLayout child's height in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to horizontally center a GridLayout that I am adding to a StackLayout. The size of the GridLayout is just big enough for it's content and does not grow or shrink. I tried adding the GridLayout to an AnchorLayout which kinda works, but I can't figure out how to set the height of the AnchorLayout to be the height of the GridLayout that I am adding to it.

I tried setting the AnchorLayout height with `height: self.children[0].height`, it doesn't work (no error, but the height is the default 100)

How do I go about setting the AnchorLayout height to the height of it's child? (or is there a better way to center the GridLayout? That is my main goal.)

Here is the example kv code:

```
<MyStackLayout>
    Label:
        text: 'header #1'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]+2
    AnchorLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.children[0].height
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 1,1,1,1
            height: self.minimum_height
            width: self.minimum_width
            size_hint: None, None
            CheckBox:
                size: 25, 25
                size_hint: None, None
            CheckBox:
                size: 25, 25
                size_hint: None, None
            CheckBox:
                size: 25, 25
                size_hint: None, None
            CheckBox:
                size: 25, 25
                size_hint: None, None
            CheckBox:
                size: 25, 25
                size_hint: None, None
            CheckBox:
                size: 25, 25
                size_hint: None, None
            CheckBox:
                size: 25, 25
                size_hint: None, None
            CheckBox:
                size: 25, 25
                size_hint: None, None
            CheckBox:
                size: 25, 25
                size_hint: None, None
            CheckBox:
                size: 25, 25
                size_hint: None, None
    Label:
        text: 'header #2'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]+2
```

And the python code for running it:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout

class MyStackLayout(StackLayout):
    pass

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyStackLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

The effect I'm going for would be something like this:

```html
<center>
  <p>header 1</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox'>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox'>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>header 2</p>
  ... more stuff here later
</center>
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Nykakin, I basically figured it out. I put an id on the GridLayout and set the height of the AnchorLayout by it.

```
AnchorLayout:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: thegrid.height
    GridLayout:
        id: thegrid
        #...
```